# Unable to select table in "reclassify by table" algorithm in QGIS Processing Modeler

Tags: qgis, batch, qgis-modeler, reclassify

In the Processing Modeler (Graphical Modeler) for QGIS 3.4.3, the "reclassify by table" tool seems bugged. I cannot select a Reclassification table, even though it's an obligatory field.
Am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What field are you talking about? If you're talking about the dropdown menu for "Reclassification table", you probably need to have a table in your project before you can select it from that menu.

Comment: It looks like that's actually in a processing model; if that's the case you'll need to load a table into the model.

Comment: Yes that's probably it! How do I load a table into the model? Is it in the "Input" section?

Comment: A table is a Matrix input.

Comment: I edited your question based on your comments. Please review the changes (they will appear after a couple of other users review and approve them) and make sure I didn't introduce any factual errors.

Comment: Be sure to press the `OK` button, as pressing the `back` button cancels all changes: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47602

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the model input "Matrix", which you then can use as an input to the function "reclassify by table". See screenshots below:

[image]

And if you open the function "reclassify by table", you need to use the matrix as an input. Make sure your matrix has 3 columns!

[image]